# Error in calling SSL enabled soap web service using Java client

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap

Can anybody suggest on sample code for calling SOAP web service client in Java.
the web service is SSL enabled.

Basically i am able to invoke by setting certificate as shown below. however this is impacting on other applications, since i am overwriting the System property.

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "jcg.pkcs12");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "test1");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keystore");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "test1");
```

Please suggest to invoke webservice Programatically passing trust store and key store? If there is any example appreciated.

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: JAX-WS and these are my steps to calling  HelloWorld locator = new HelloWorld();
        HelloWorldService request = locator.getHandlePWRequestPort();
        int returnCode = request.sayHello("name");

Comment: Keystore is only required when `two way SSL handshake` is required, if only SSL needs to be enabled then it is not required. Do you need to do two way SSL Handshake, meaning `does your server want to validate if request is initiated from valid client`?